# Executing mono on Apache

Tags: c#, php, apache, mono

I have a PHP script that calls a C# program with mono:

```
exec("/opt/mono/bin/mono myprog.exe param1 param2");
```

When I execute my script on terminal as root:

```
# php myscript.php
```

myprog.exe is executed normally. But when I try to execute this script as apache user (on browser user click in submit button with form action = myscript.php) I received error 11 on PHP exec function. What am I doing wrong?

I already made

```
chmod 777 /opt/mono/bin/mono
```

and in the program that I am running

```
chmod 755 myprog.exe
```

myprog.exe is in apache folder /var/www/html.

I'm using CentOS on Azure and mono version 3.2.8 (installed as described in https://gist.github.com/andreazevedo/9479518)

This is happening only in server. At my local machine its working.

Comment: maybe you should look into [mod mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/) instead and cut out PHP as the middle man?

Comment: thanks, I will see it. But I still wondering why this is happening.

Comment: Apache runs things as a different user and group than when you run the application from the CLI. It maybe that the mono application is accessing a file that the apache user does not have permissions for.

Comment: Following [Vic Seedoubleyew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021) answer I disable SELinux and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

> I received error 11 on PHP exec

Error 11 is segmentation fault. PHP is reading and executing myprog.exe properly. But mono/myprog.exe ITSELF is breaking.

If you can execute it fine as your user it maybe that apache or php is not allowing enough memory to be used for mono/myprog.exe? Check your configs.

Comment: How can I check this?